# Algorithm to detected number of squares in given image

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have an image in which there are various nested squares. I want to detect number of squares in that image using Matlab.

I have already found all the corners in the image:

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jyjxji7QjtU/UJ6M8lGiwbI/AAAAAAAAAEs/zSNc_JdjPkU/w348-h353-p-k/123.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

Use the Matlab function `houghlines` (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) to detect line segments in the image.  Then iterate over each line segment and find all the other line segments that have endpoints close by.  Take the angle with each nearby segment and look for 90 degree angles.  If you can find the right arrangement of lines at 90 degree angles to make a square, then you've detected a square.